# Difference between React Custom Hooks and Regular Functions

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between a regular JS function, a helper/service function and React Custom Hook?

The similar answers I found didn't give any good examples, so I created this "service" function that I'll be using for example to list some users in an other Function Component :

```
import axios from "axios";

const useService = () => {
  const fields = [
    { key: "name", _style: { width: "40%" } },
    { key: "email", _style: { width: "40%" } },
  ];

  const getUsers = async () => {
    return await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users");
  };

  const getBadge = (status) => {
    switch (status) {
      case "Active":
        return "success";
      case "Inactive":
        return "secondary";
      case "Pending":
        return "warning";
      case "Banned":
        return "danger";
      default:
        return "primary";
    }
  };

  return { fields, getUsers, getBadge };
};

export default useService;
```

I called it `useService` but I didn't actually use any React hooks here like  `useEffect`, `useState` etc.. So is this function still a Custom Hook? Is it just a utility/helper function?

What is the difference exactly when we talk about Custom Hooks & Utility/Helper/Service/Normal Functions etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is this function still a Custom Hook? Is it just a utility/helper function?

No it isn't a hook.

Hooks use a stateful closure around the invocation of the function component to store state on behalf of that component instance. That closure is maintained by React.

I needed to read [Deep dive: How do React hooks really work](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/) before I could wrap my head around hooks.

Recently I also came across:

- [Vanilla Hooks (outside React)](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/vanilla-hooks-outside-react-860471e5f95c)
- [Hooks in a Nutshell](https://gist.github.com/WebReflection/77b005e5693cf5e5c1fa1ea781b673d8)

Comment: So just wanna see if I get it right:
1. `use` is just a prefix for enabling eslint to check whether the rules of hooks is complied.
2. The only thing that separates helper function and hooks are whether there're other hooks being used within

Comment: @TKforce - afaik the `use` prefix is simply a convention established by the [Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) itself. The convention extends to custom hooks serving as an indicator that the functions internally use the React Hooks API (or other custom hooks that do) - thus making them also subject to the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). So [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) may well leverage that convention.

Comment: Why not? You didn't give any meaningful explanations, just claimed "no, it's not".

Comment: @mimic Unless somewhere, somehow one of React's own hooks is called (while still in accordance with the "Rules of Hooks") a `useX` function is not a custom hook. The code in the original question doesn't use any of React's own hooks nor does it use any custom hooks that do. That is what I meant when I stated "That closure is maintained by React".

Comment: @PeerReynders a custom hook may but shouldn't use React hooks. Show me the original document saying it "should" use them.

Comment: @mimic "You can also write your own Hooks by combining the existing ones." https://beta.reactjs.org/learn#sharing-data-between-components "existing ones" means React's own hooks.

Comment: @PeerReynders it says "you **can** also write your own Hooks by combining the existing ones". That means you "can" but it's not mandatory. It doesn't say "you should".

Comment: @mimic https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook "but every time you use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully isolated." ... "Each *call* to a Hook gets isolated state. Because we call `useFriendStatus` directly, from React’s point of view our component just calls `useState` and `useEffect`." So the implication is that isolated state is a consequence of using React's own hooks somewhere. The `use` prefix is used to flag ESLint that React's hooks are in use and therefore the "Rules of Hooks" have to be complied with.

Answer (score 2):

> So is this function still a Custom Hook? Is it just a utility/helper function?

It starts with `use`, so if it's used in a React component, React will recognize it as a valid custom hook - that is, hooks can be used inside of it. Even if it isn't using any hooks inside, it'll still qualify as one - but if you don't use any hooks inside, whether it qualifies as a hook itself or not doesn't matter, since the distinction would never be checked or have any impact.

To avoid confusion, I'd suggest only adding `use` to function names if the functions implement hooks and are meant to be custom hooks.

As the [docs say](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook):

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.

You don't *have* to call other hooks inside your custom hook - but if you're aiming to make a custom hook in the first place, you *probably want* to be calling other hooks like `useState`. Otherwise, calling your custom utility function something else that *doesn't* start with `use` would probably make more sense - despite the fact that whether you do or don't doesn't directly impact how the code runs.

Comment: Yes I understand the thing about the `use` keyword, I'm not really asking if the code will run the same or not, I just need to understand the idea behind all this. So the moment I use any react hook inside the function above, at that moment it becomes `stateful`, meaning it becomes a Custom Hook? and without that it is exactly the same as any normal JS function? Is this correct?

Comment: It'll only be "stateful" if you use state with `useState` inside (or something that implements `useState`). Even without any hooks inside, your function still fits the definition of a custom hook, since it starts with `use` and is used in a React component. But it's *confusing* because a function that indicates that it's a custom hook should do *something* that only a custom hook can do.

Comment: @CertainPerformance "It'll only be "stateful" if you use state with useState inside"
What is the implication of stateful being in quotes? I don't see why OPs function is not capable of storing state if they wanted to.

Comment: @GHOST-34 I was referring to OP's wording when he said in the comment *at that moment it becomes `stateful`, meaning it becomes a Custom Hook?* - yes, it absolutely could be stateful if he wanted to use `useState`, but he isn't, so it's not really stateful at the moment - it's just a function hook.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Nevermind the fact that it was crafted as a hook with the "use" prefix. If it were not, and was simply a regular function, how could it not still be stateful?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, custom hook is just a function. It should prefix the function name with `use`. In most cases, the hooks provided by react are grouped together into functional units, but it is not mandatory.
You can see some practical custom hooks for reference here.

https://usehooks.com/